# Is WebRTC safe for connecting random clients to each other?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, p2p, webrtc

I am trying to implement a chatroulette-sque app, and WebRTC seems to be the best choice as far implementing something that doesn't take a vast amount of server resources. My current scheme is to create a WebSocket connection to my server to be able to establish a connection between two random hosts. However the downside of that is that I am forced to exchange their details. Is the most potentially harmful data that is being shared an IP address? and if so what could the IP be used for? or are there bigger things I need to worry about?

Comment: Note that leaking IP Address also leaks your location, which is fine if you're chatting with someone you know, but may be problematic if you are chatting with strangers and could be used to personally identify you if you have static IP Address so it may become a privacy issue.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of IP address leakage you might want to see [How bad is the leaking of Internal IP addresses through external DNS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/how-bad-is-the-leaking-of-internal-ip-addresses-through-external-dns).

Nowadays, WebRTC works only on HTTPS and you should also use WebSockets on wss instead of ws. And I guess this way you should be fine.